# XAMARIN IOS APP Closes automatically on launching with no crash report

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

The ios app was working fine and I was working and debugging on the simulator, suddenly the app starts and closes, no crash report. The app closes after loading the assembly as per what I can see from the application output log with no crash report. Even the debugger detaches and stopped debugging and comes to it default play state. [image]

Lastly I also see the this error " The call is ambiguous between the calling methods App.InitializeComponent() and App.InitializeComponent(). Basically for all Xaml Pages.

I tried reinstalling all the packages and updating for all Packages(shared/ios/android) but still issue persist.
Screenshot of the package installed.[image]

Comment: A common and routine option that might help would be cleaning solution, deleting obj/bin folders, and also removing Nuget caches.

Comment: @Vahid tried deleting obj/bin folder, cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Don't post images, post the code and logs as text.

Comment: Try to uninstall App from simulator and Again deploy and test on it.